# putty window title changes after loading saved session

Tags: ssh, putty

I am connecting to a saved session that I set up before. I followed the usual steps of going to:

`Window` -> `Behaviour` set title: `Window title`.

`Terminal` -> `Features` check `Disable remote-controlled window title changing`.

Then I saved my session and closed. I then tried to reload this session again, the title I set appears for a brief second then it resets to something else again

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you clarify your post? You're not asking a precise, clear question right now.

Comment: The question is how do I get this change to be permanent rather than resetting every time I load a saved session? I was of the understanding that if I saved the session with all settings configured then I wouldn't need to configure it again every time I load the session.